# Understanding static in C#

Tags: c#

I'm learning C# and I'm having trouble understanding the `static` keyword.

Say I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;

class PortThing
{
    SerialPort port;

    void InitPort()
    {
        if(!File.Exists("/dev/whatever"))
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Device not found.");    
            port = null;  
        }
        //else port = something
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InitPort();
        System.Console.WriteLine("Done.");
    }
}
```

As far as I can understand, a static method is one that belongs to the class rather than to the object of that class. So static methods can't reference nonstatic methods/fields since they require instantiating a class.

Compiler complains about `Main()` calling `InitPort()` and wants to make it static. I could do so but that would require to make `port` a static field. Following this line of thought, everything would end up being static.

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are getting it right. Static methods can access only static members. Non-static members need an instance of the class in order to access them. So you could do this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new PortThing().InitPort();
    System.Console.WriteLine("Done.");
}
```

This way you are calling the instance method `InitPort` on a given class instance and you can keep the `port` field non-static.

Comment: all static members... not just static fields

Comment: Your example contradicts your explanation.  Why don't you rewrite the second sentence (maybe mention something about how non-static members need an instance, the static Main method doesn't have a default instance, so you have to provide one explicitly), then you'll have my vote.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    PortThing pt = new PortThing();
    pt.InitPort();
    System.Console.WriteLine("Done.");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting nothing wrong.

The issue here is that `Main` would not need to be `static` in a normal class. It needs to be static here because it provides the *entry point* to your program. In other words, you need to have a method to run, but you can't create an object before running, so that method has to be `static`.

There is nothing preventing you from actually creating an object of class `PortThing` and using it normally:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var pt = new PortThing();
    pt.InitPort();
    System.Console.WriteLine("Done.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You got that correctly: a static method belongs to the class rather than the object.

But in this case, if you don't want to make everything static, you could simply create an object of type PortThing, in other words, instantiate this class, and call the non-static method.

Or, if that non-static method does not access any class properties, at least non-static ones, you COULD make it static.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods and variables are availabe without an instance of the class.

The most important thing to know about static variables is that there is only one instance of that variable per process (more accurately AppDomain, however most processes have only 1 AppDomain). I think of static variables as global variables. You can create static constructors of a class to initialize these static variables. The static constructor is called once, when that class is first accessed. But be aware of concurrency issues regarding multi-threaded applications that access and modify static members, especially static collections!!

Static methods can be thought as a function in C. They can be called without creating any object, which is slightly better for performance (but should only be used in places where they make sense). For example, I would implement the method int CountNumberOfCommas(string s) as a static method in a static utility class, since this is an operation that's independent of any instance of a class.

You are not doing anything wrong. You just have to choose between two options: You can create an instance of Program and call InitPort, or make InitPort static, and not create an instance of Program. Making everything static is essentially the same as writing a program in C, where you only define functions.